# How Can i add little icon to actionbar in this specific code

Tags: android

I've been searching for many questions, but there were not proper for myself.

I need one line to code to this:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#547AF7</item>
</style>
```

PROBLEM: How to add little icon on the left

edit ()
I do not know why this doesnt work :

```
<item name="icon">@drawable/icon</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

The use of application icon and title is discouraged in API Level 21, according to **material design** guidelines.

But if you want to set icon, you could use *setLogo()* method of Toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use:

```
<item name="android:background">@drawable/YOURIMAGENAMEHERE</item>
```

Or read this:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html

Comment: but i have got my own background color, i want just attach icon

Answer (score 0):

You can add icon on ActionBar using `android:icon="@drawable/your_icon.png"`

`<application> or <activity>` tags in your app manifest.

for more See the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#icon) :

Comment: it shows as icon of app but not in the actionbar :/

Comment: set the icon attribute of activity for which you want icon on action bar.
This attribute sets the specified icon on the left side action bar